# Share images on whatsapp from wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, share, whatsapp

I have a WordPress blog. I would like to let my viewers share certain images on **WhatsApp**.

I allow them to share text and URLs using `whatsapp://send?text=abc http://example.com`. However, I can't figure out a way to let them share images.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, WhatsApp does not have any public API you can use. (ref, this [link](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-use-WhatsApp-to-share-images-from-a-website))

But you can play with this API used in this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/whatsapp/)

`whatsapp://send?text='.get_the_title().' - '.get_permalink()'`